# Multiple values for given key in python

Tags: python-2.7

I have multiple players playing various sports.

i.e.

**Football:**

1. Lionel Messi
2. Cristiano Ronaldo.
3. Andres Iniesta

**Cricket:**

1. Sachin Tendulakar
2. Shane Warne
3. Ricky Ponting

**Tennis:**

1. Roger Federer
2. Andy Murray
3. Novak Djokovic

**Running:**

1. Usain Bolt
2. Yohan Blake
3. Tyson Gay

So I will enter name of any player from above list.
My python program should output the name of sport that player is playing.

I am not sure which data structures I should be using fro this as I am novice in python.

Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: What is the code that you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it

```
playermap = {
'cricket' : ['sachin tendulkar', 'ricky ponting', 'shane warne'],
'running' : ['bolt', 'tyson gay'],
'tennis' : ['murray', 'federer']
}

desiredplayer = raw_input('Enter player to find sport:\n')
found = False
for sport, players in playermap.iteritems():
    if desiredplayer.strip().lower() in players:
        print sport
        found = True

if not found:
    print "player not found in any sport"
```